# WordPress changes URL on admin page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

We have 2 projects. **https://host/** - first (on Node.js), **https://host/modules/** - second (on WP). Before that nginx stays as reverse-proxy. When I'm on page 'modules', everything is good, but when I go **https://host/modules/wp-admin/**, URL becomes as **https://host/wp-admin**, and links in menu lose prefix /modules/ as well. Somewhere are right links. What's happening there and when should I dig?

I tried also the settings .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /modules/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /modules/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it makes no results. Settings **siteurl** and **home** are **https://host/modules/**. Please, I pray for getting some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via Docker, nginx and wordpress:*-php*-fpm containers (wp also requires mysql).

Folders structure:

```
nginx_data  
- wordpress.conf  
wp  
- modules
```

There is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_data:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./wp:/var/www/html

  modules:
      image: wordpress:4.9-php7.1-fpm-alpine
      volumes:
        - ./wp/modules:/var/www/html/modules
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - mysql

    mysql:
      image: mysql
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      volumes:
        - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://some_host;
  }

  location /modules {
    try_files $uri $uri/  /modules/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass modules:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}
```

**And one important moment:** you must move files in wp-container from `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/html/modules`**!**